# selinux on RHEL6: httpd config. DocumentRoot [/path/does/exist] "does not exist"

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, selinux, rhel6

I'm running a stock RHEL6 installation and have pointed my httpd DocumentRoot to `/path/does/exist` (it exists!).  I've granted permission to the `apache` user and added what I thought should be the necessary label via:

```
chcon -R  -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/does
```

**but no dice**.

`audit2why` shows a missing type enforcement allow rule for a request that looks like

```
avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=4793
   comm="httpd" name="/"  
   scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 
   tcontext=system_u:object_r:file_t:s0 
   tclass=dir
```

Can someone help me interpret?  Please note that I'm not looking for the answer "disable selinux" :-)

Thanks!

-B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to apply the following (assuming that path is /www)

```
chcon -R -u system_u /www
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /www
```

And then make it survive a label:

```
semanage fcontext -a -s system_u -t httpd_sys_content_t /www
```

What I find it is easier to use another directory as a template when apply SELinux context to a directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 www
[root@kvm0001 /]# chcon --reference=/var/www www
[root@kvm0001 /]# ls -laZ
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 www
[root@kvm0001 /]#
```